# String to Int shall throw instead of returning 0

Tags: php, casting

If I cast a string with `intval('string')` or with `(int) 'string'` 
and if that string contains letters other than numbers I get `int 0` as result.

Is there a way in which an catchable Exception is thrown, due to which I can check that the conversion was successful,  so that the user can't accidentally enter `1O` instead of `10`?

Also is there a way to check for float?

Comment: Casting to an int won't raise errors. Even though that's arguably idiotic. You can of course write code that checks whether a string is numeric and raise an error if it isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `preg_match("/\D/", 'string')` would work for this.
This function looks for a certain pattern in a string and returns true if it finds the pattern and false if it doesn't.

The delimiter \D checks for non-digits, such as 0 and the forward slashes are for opening and closing the delimiter section.

So, as it will return true when it find a non-digit value, you'll have to throw an error or return early from your program when this returns true. When it's false, everything is fine

Comment: Might need to `trim()` that string to remove leading/trailing blanks because those also would be "non-digits."  I admit that the behavior of `intval()` in JS is quite nonsensical.

Answer (score -1):

```
class Number {
private $value;

public function __construct($value) {
    $this->setValue($value);
}

public function getValue(): float {
    return $this->value;
}

public function getIntValue(): int {
    return intval($this->value);
}

public function setValue($value) {
    if (!is_numeric($value)) {
        throw new Exception("$value is not numeric");
    }
    $this->value;
} }
```

Comment: So basically you're telling me that i should use `is_numeric($value)` ?

Comment: Also in `setValue()` you surely mean `$this->value = $value;` instead of `$this->value;`

Comment: Also why would `getValue()` return a `float` if you never made sure `$this->value` is a  `float`.  I could just make `(new Number('hi))->getValue()` and have a `TypeError`